# Strange behaviour when calling python functions from cython c

Tags: python, c++, callback, python-c-api

I have some C++ code, some python code and some cython code.
In C++, I have an asynchronous callback that gets executed, and I want python code to be executed.

Here's what I did.
In python, I wrote a function that took 2 parameters:

```
def fn(x,y):
    print("hello")
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Then, in C++,  I wanted to call this function "fn" asynchronously as a callback.
So I created a C++ function called "PythonCallback" to wrap the callback.

```
class PythonCallback{
public:
    PyObject *_pyfunc;

    PythonCallback(PyObject *pyfunc);
    void presentCallback(_bstr_t EventName, BYTE* CallbackData);
    void addCallbackToGUID( PyObject* Py_GUID );
}


//Constructor
PythonCallback::PythonCallback(PyObject *pyfunc){
if( PyCallable_Check(pyfunc)){
    Py_INCREF(pyfunc);
    _pyfunc = pyfunc;
}else{
    throw -1;
}
};

void PythonCallback::presentCallback(_bstr_t EventName, BYTE* pCallbackData)
{
PyGILState_STATE gstate;
gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
EventData* evData = (EventData*)pCallbackData;
PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(ss)", EventName, EventName);
const wchar_t* wstring(EventName);
PyObject_CallObject(_pyfunc, args );

std::wstring w;
w.append(EventName);
//    PyObject_CallFunction( _pyfunc, "(ss)", wstring, wstring);
//    PyObject_CallFunction( _pyfunc, "(ss)", w.c_str(),w.c_str());
//    PyObject_CallFunction( _pyfunc, "(s)", w.c_str() );
//    PyObject_CallFunction( _pyfunc, "" );
//    PyObject_CallFunction( _pyfunc, "ss", wstring, wstring );

PyGILState_Release(gstate);

};
```

And all of this is glued together with Cython.
In Cython, I created a class that would send the python function to C++

```
cdef class CallbackInformation:
    cdef PythonCallback *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, object func):
        self.thisptr = new PythonCallback(func)
        # temp = PythonCallback(func)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def addCallbackToGUID(self,guid):
        self.thisptr.addCallbackToGUID(guid)
```

So, then what I would do is create a new instance of `CallbackInformation` and pass it the `fn`. i.e. `instance = CallbackInformation(fn)`

The problem happens when I call the python callback function `fn`.
I don't get an immediate error, but when I try to just check `fn` in the python console, i.e. if I just type fn in the console, I get the following error:

> File "C:/Users/eric/PycharmProjects/SuperResolution/Startup3dCalibration.py", >line 62, in fn
>      print("hello")
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid >start byte

if I do it again,
I get his message

> hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello

and finally, if I do it a third time, I get the expected output:
`<function fn at 0x0000000002281048>`

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet again, the solution comes right after you post the question:

so I realized that with `Py_BuildValue`,  there's a fundamental difference between a `char *` string and a unicode string. So, simply replacing `PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(ss)", EventName, EventName);` with `PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(uu)", EventName, EventName);` fixed my problem.

I guess the error about unconvertable unicode makes sense in the end.